# NAudio WaveOut.GetCapabilities().ProductName returns invalid characters in the device name

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, waveout

Our application uses NAudio WaveOut to get audio devices connected to user computer. In this particular case, the use has windows machine running in Polish language. Therefore, when we enumerate the devices, WaveOut returns invalid characters in the Name of the devices.

For example. The device name should be "Głośniki (Urządzenie zgodne ze standardem High Definition Audio)"

But WaveOut returns something like this

Gԯݮiki (Urzڤzenie zgodne ze

Probably it is a case of UTF-8 encoding, which is missing in this case.

Will need help to fix this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake.. WaveOut.GetCapabilites() does returns strings in Unicode by default. We were printing it out in our logs as ansi-code and,therefore was printed incorrectly and presumed it to be incorrect.